# Git says "Warning: Permanently added to the list of known hosts"

Tags: git, shell, command-line, ssh, terminal

Every time I use git to interact with a remote, such as when pulling or pushing, I am shown the following message:

> Warning: Permanently added '...' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

How can I prevent this annoying message from displaying? It is only an annoyance—everything functions properly.

Comment: Do you really mean *every* time? Is it giving you a prompt of the form `The authenticity of host '...' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is .... Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`, or have you suppressed that? If it is, is it the same fingerprint every time? If it's not, that's **really scary**. The less scary option would be that somehow it's not actually managing to write to the hosts file, so it tries again every time. Have a look at `~/.ssh/known_hosts`?

Comment: Yes. <i>Every</i> time. However, I don't see the "Are you sure..." message - maybe I've suppressed it.

Comment: Is the host listed in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`? (Is it listed 5000 times?) Does `~/.ssh/config` exist/contain anything (especially a value for `StrictHostKeyChecking`)?

Comment: The host is listed in that file once, and it is the only entry.

Comment: @JackB. Is the file readable/writable? What about by users other than you (ssh will ignore it if so)? Your `~/.ssh` directory needs to be mod 700 in order for SSH to pay any attention at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the permissions as suggested didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Jefromi The config file contains "StrictHostKeyChecking no"

Comment: That's *exactly* what suppresses the warning message, and that's not there by default. However, since there's only one host, it sounds like it's supplying the same key every time. If remove/comment that line, then with every push/pull do you see the same message, with the same key?

Comment: I tried removing "StrictHostKeyChecking no", but that caused the server to be rejected.

Comment: I'm guessing the contents of your `known_hosts` file are bad.  It should be the host key, on one terribly long line.  If you only have the host name there (for example) it will not work.  I recommend that you remove this file (if indeed it only contains the information for this single host) and allow SSH to create it next time you connect.  It should be silent after that.

Comment: In general, if a program invokes ssh and ssh misbehaves, the first thing to try is running ssh on its own to connect to the same host and see what happens.

Comment: tripleee, I tried deleting the "known_hosts" file so that it could be recreated, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Create a `~/.ssh/config` file and insert the line:

```
UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You will then see the message the next time you access Github, but after that you'll not see it anymore because the host is added to the `known_hosts` file.  This fixes the issue, rather than just hiding the log message.

This problem was bugging me for quite some time.  The problem occurs because the OpenSSH client compiled for Windows doesn't check the known_hosts file in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

ssh -vvv git@github.com

```
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't consider suppressing warnings or errors a proper solution to a problem.  ;)

Comment: recently, I faced same issue on my ubuntu machine. It started to behave this way after I used a different (from my default `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) key to connect to a server. As @JeremiahGowdy mentioned, I have `debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "172.16.3.101" from file "/dev/null"`. Why does SSH starts using `/dev/null` as known_hosts after I changed key?

Comment: Works great! Finally the stupid warning stopped. Btw on Windows, the `~` in `~/.ssh/config` is the user's home folder. To open it easily, Press **Win-R**, type `cmd` *Enter*. Command prompt should already open in your home folder. Type `cd .ssh` *Enter*, and then `start .` *Enter* to open the folder in Windows Explorer. Then you can create the **config** file in Notepad (no **.txt** extension when saving). *(Pro users can echo directly to a new file in command prompt itself `;)`).* Run a git command involving *remote* twice (like `git fetch`), and you're done.

Comment: why do you have 20 v's for ssh?

Comment: @bubakazouba The more v's, the more verbose the log gets, check the docs for that. Three would suffice, twenty are an overkill :D

Comment: Yeah, holding down v for a second is faster than checking the docs to determine the maximum number of useful v's

Comment: Worked for me on OSX High Sierra as well. Afterwards I had to remove the key though and log in another two times.. Makes me wonder if just replacing the offending key would have worked as well as Larry Cai mentioned in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16432171/460885

Comment: I was curious if the evolution of macOS system versions would change the steps the take here in the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 99):

Add the following line to your ssh config file ($HOME/.ssh/config):

```
LogLevel=quiet
```

If running ssh from the command line add the following option to the command string:

```
-o LogLevel=quiet
```

For example, the following prints out the gcc version installed on machine.example.org (and no warning):

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o LogLevel=quiet \
    -i identity_file \
    machine.example.org \
    gcc -dumpversion
```

Comment: Adding "LogLevel=quiet" to the "config" file worked. Thank you.

Comment: To maintain security, it would be good to put the "LogLevel=quiet" inside a "Host" section.

Comment: `LogLevel=quiet` is a bad idea, he wants all errors to be displayed, he just want to avoid this specific obnoxious error. Probably because he tricked ssh to use `/dev/null` as the `known_hosts` file, probably because he wanted to turn off `known_hosts` fingerprint checking, but couldn't, because ssh overlords didn't allow him to.

Comment: @bukzor `loglevel=error` still displays "Connection to <server> closed" when the connection is terminated, which is also really annoying for scripting.

Comment: I downvoted this as it doesn't really solve the problem. It just hides it.

Answer (score 69):

Set `LogLevel` to `ERROR` (not `QUIET`) in `~/.ssh/config` file to avoid seeing these errors:

```
Host *
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
   LogLevel ERROR
```

Comment: This worked best in my case - or you can specify "-oLogLevel=ERROR" on the command line

Comment: I use these settings only for local ips and hosts which are mostly vms where the hostkey changes relatively often: `Host 192.* 10.* *.mylocal.domain`.

Comment: Super smart =)) this one works perfectly and simply: `LogLevel ERROR`

Answer (score 8):

That message is from SSH, which is warning you that you are connecting to a host which you've never connected to before. I wouldn't recommend turning it off, since it would mean that you might miss a warning about a host key changing, which can indicate a MITM attack on your SSH session.

Comment: But I connect to it 10-15 times each day, and still I receive this warning.

Comment: @JackB. Look at `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and see if your host is in there.

Comment: Is the key changing for some reason? Check the fingerprint in the file vs the fingerprint that is output by ssh. Also, is the mode of your .ssh directory set to 0700?

Comment: @JasonCarreiro, I'm a big boy, I know no one will pull MITM attack inside my rack, security is a tradeoff, and I want new computers to work out of the box with preshared key, with no need to manage a CA or `ssh-keyscan`.

Answer (score 5):

To suppress warning messages for `ssh` you can add the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
LogLevel error
```

That will disable warnings but not error messages. Like the other settings in `~/.ssh/config` you can configure the `LogLevel` on a per-host basis if you want a more finegrained control.

Answer (score 4):

It mainly means there are changes for the key for that host `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, and it will not automatically UPDATE it. Therefore every time you get this warning message.

This happens often for the connecting to the re-created virtual machines, which changes the key with the same IP address

**Solution**

If you only have one entry, then you can delete the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and after first connection, that the key will be there, and no warning messages after that.

If you have multiple entries, then you can use command below to remove

```
$ ssh-keygen -R <hostname>
```

It works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Add ssh key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "abc@abc.com"

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa
```

crate config file

```
crate ~/.ssh/config
```

add below line.

```
UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Then add pub key and clone your repository... Done.....

Answer (score 1):

add your private key to the ssh-agent with:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a repository from GitHub, consider using the **HTTPS** version of the URL instead, to sidestep this problem entirely:

[image: Click the HTTP button and clone that URL instead]

If you clone your repository from within the Windows GitHub application, this is what it uses for the remote URL. Maybe they know something we don't know.

Comment: Note: If you use private key authentication, you cannot use HTTP(S).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and I found there is not a `.ssh` file in my `~`. So I just create the `.ssh` directory under `~` path, and the issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same issue when I started using a Windows machine. In my case it was because my SSH setup was not done. Github has a very precise documentation on the SSH setup. Once that's taken care, the issue was resolved.

https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same error in Linux/Cent OS VM and it was because the IP was changing after restart. In order to get around this problem, I defined a static IP in the network and added that entry to `/etc/hosts` file. For static IP mention a slightly higher range value. For example if your current IP (ipconfig/ifconfig) is 192.168.0.102, next time after restart this may become 192.168.0.103. So define your static IP in IPV4 settings as 192.168.0.181 which should do the trick.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the admin who set up the server set these options in `~/.ssh/config`

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Which worked fine for most cases by not using the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. But for the enterprise gitlab repo, every time it gave the "Warning: Permanently added ... to the list of known hosts."

My solution was to comment out the `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null` line, which allowed the creation of `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Then it didn't give any more warnings after that.

You might also have a old/invalid entries in your `known_hosts`.

```sh
# find entry in ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keygen -F <hostname>

# delete entry in ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keygen -R <hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case I only got the ssh warning when using Gridengine `qrsh` remote shell login. Whereas a normal `ssh` would work as expected (warning first time, then quiet subsequent times).

My solution was to manually fill `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with all the possible server names that Gridengine could choose (use `qhost` to list the servers):

```
for p in server1 server2 server3 server4; do
  ssh-keyscan -H ${p}.company.com;
  ssh-keyscan -H $(getent hosts $p | perl -lane 'print $F[0]');
done >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Background:

Gridengine is a job scheduler which can use ssh to select the least loaded server. The reason for the warning is that `qrsh` seem to always specify a non-standard port for doing the ssh connection, causing `known_hosts` to be updated with an entry also containing a port number. Next time when `qrsh` selects the same server there would be a new port-number and `known_hosts` would get updated with a new port-specific entry. The reason for also adding the raw host IP address is that some hosts used `ecdsa-sha2-nistp521`. If a raw IP entry is not added I would get the warning:

```
ECDSA host key for IP address '10.1.2.3' not in list of known hosts.
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need this command.

If it is, use GitHub:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

If you use GitLab:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no clean solution for the problem you noted as far as I am aware.
The previously suggested /dev/null redirection will still display the warning, it just disables the security feature of storing the remote keys by redirecting the output into /dev/null.
So ssh would still think it writes something which is actually discarded.

As I know the only option is to catch the message and remove it from stdout.

```
ssh/scp..... 2>&1 | grep -v "^Warning: Permanently added"
```

Here is a complete example that you can use as wrapper to hide such warnings:

```
#!/bin/bash
remove="^Warning: Permanently added" # message to remove from output

cmd=${0##*/}

case $cmd in
 ssh)
  binary=/usr/bin/ssh
 ;;
 *)
  echo "unsupported binary ($0)"
  exit
 ;;
esac
$binary "$@" 2>&1 | grep -v "$remove"
```

To install it all you need to do is add/modify the "case" statement for the actual command you wish to modify. (ssh, scp, git etc).
the "ssh)"  means the script has to be named "ssh" (or a link to the script is named ssh).
The binary=/full/path is the path to the binary the script should wrap.
Then put the script with a name of your choice into /bin or somewhere else.

The script also the place where you can use a *-o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"* to the $binary variable, that's a lot better than putting such a security risk into the global ssh configuration which will affect all your ssh sessions and not just those you want to supress the message.

Disadvantages:
It's a bit overhead, not a perfectly clean solution and moves stderr into stdout which might not be good in all cases.
But it will get rid of any sort of warning messages you don't wish to see and you can use a single script to wrap all binaries you want (by using filesystem links to it)